# reload=true not working in @click function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was working on currency switcher. i call method on click the link and after method successful want it to reload. but reload is not working at all. currency getting stored in cookie, if i refresh page manually it gets updated in navbar too, but i want it to reload automatically once method complete.

here is the code in navbar..

```html
<b-dropdown position="is-bottom-left" aria-role="menu">
  <template #trigger>
    <a class="navbar-item font-bold" role="button">
      {{currency}}
      <b-icon icon="menu-down"></b-icon>
    </a>
  </template>
  <b-dropdown-item v-for="(item, index) in currencies" :key="index" has-link aria-role="menuitem">
    <a class="no-underline" @click="setCurrency(item.iso, (reload = true))"><span class="text-pink-600 font-bold">{{item.fullname}} ({{item.iso}})</span></a>
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

this is method.

```js
methods: {
  setCurrency(newcurrency) {
    this.$cookies.set(`usercurrency`, newcurrency, {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    })
  // window.location.href = '/'
  }
}
```

I thought to use `window.location.href = '/'` after setting cookie but i can't do it because i am using the same method in created hook like below code to set currency based on user country and it will say window not defined.

```js
created() {
  const isCurrency = this.$cookies.get('usercurrency')
  const isUserCountry = this.$cookies.get('usercountry')
  if (isCurrency === undefined) {
    if (isUserCountry === undefined) {
      fetch('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=*********')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
          const country = jsonResponse.country
          this.$cookies.set(`usercountry`, country, {
            path: '/',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
          })
          var CurrencyParam
          switch (country) {
            case 'IN':
            case 'NP':
              CurrencyParam = 'INR'
              break
            case 'US':
              CurrencyParam = 'USD'
              break
            case 'AU':
              CurrencyParam = 'AUD'
              break
            case 'CA':
              CurrencyParam = 'CAD'
              break
            case 'GB':
              CurrencyParam = 'GBP'
              break
            case 'AE':
              CurrencyParam = 'AED'
              break
            case 'RU':
              CurrencyParam = 'RUB'
              break
            case 'JP':
              CurrencyParam = 'JPY'
              break
            case 'SG':
              CurrencyParam = 'SGD'
              break
            case 'FR':
            case 'FI':
            case 'DE':
            case 'GR':
            case 'HU':
            case 'IT':
            case 'LT':
            case 'MT':
            case 'NL':
            case 'NO':
            case 'PL':
            case 'PT':
            case 'RO':
            case 'RS':
            case 'ES':
            case 'SE':
            case 'CH':
            case 'UA':
              CurrencyParam = 'EUR'
              break
            default:
              CurrencyParam = 'USD'
          }
          this.setCurrency(CurrencyParam)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          this.setCurrency('USD')
        })
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: So you're nuking the whole SPA here??

Comment: may be my approach is perfectly wrong here ! can you suggest some other way to achieve this as i am using nuxt. i am very new to vue and nuxtjs. i would love to follow your idea in implementing this

Comment: Usually, in Vue (or Nuxt, the same in this case), you're working with state that is reactive and updates when you touch it properly. Here, you will be nuking the whole SPA, which will have a lot of issues in terms of performance, on top of breaking everything. So yeah, this is 100% wrong. I'm not sure how you're handling the currency in your app, but you should mutate this one **only** and not nuke the page. As of how exactly, it depends and it will take a decent amount of time to rewrite properly. You could probably google on ways to handle i18n, because it is somehow similar here.

Comment: Why not set your currencies up in a JSON file, or at least an array?  Your code would be much cleaner.

Comment: @Paul there are indeed several ways to improve the code here.

Comment: @kissu , i want to understand, how this nukes the page. i am really trying to understand everything you said, also i looked for nuxt i18n module, where i can use currency by number localization but is there any solution to redirect user to exact country, because i can see an option there to redirect using browser language but the problem is some english language countries set english united states as default, if i will put USD as currency for en-US and if user is from india has en-US in his browser, how can i redirect him to en-IN forcely or is there any other option there.

Comment: @V.Thakur this nukes the page because you're reloading the tab and breaking the SPA. If you google articles to understand how an SPA works, you'll see that an F5 or a paste and submit in the URL will break the SPA: you'll see your page flashing in blank. I was talking about i18n regarding the way it is implemented, you could do the same for currency but it's not directly a solution per-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution might be to pass `reload` as an optional parameter to `setCurrency`

```js
methods: {
    setCurrency(newcurrency, reload) {
        this.$cookies.set(`usercurrency`, newcurrency, {
            path: '/',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
        })
        if (reload) window.location.href = '/'
    }
}
```